# What is the folder location of dev boot mnt home folders in the disk?

Tags: linux, boot, partitioning, filesystems, arch-linux

When I was installing Arch Linux, even before I create the partitions if I type `lsblk` I get

```
loop0
Sda (no sub partitions)
Sr0 (CD ROM is mounted)
```

Now in the terminal when I type `pwd`
I get

> /root

So just being curious I did

```
ls /
```

And it showed folders like `bin boot dev lib mnt etc`.

So my question is if the partitions aren't made yet and no data is stored, then why does `ls /` show all of these folders? At what location in the disk are these folders stored?.
Also, there are already  folders for `/`  `/mnt` and `/boot` 
So I'm not able to understand why we make new partitions for root , boot
 Then mount these partitions to `/mnt` and `/boot`
Can someone help me with this.
Im following the tutorial from https://itsfoss.com/install-arch-linux/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't expect `"/"` to represent any specific disk – that's not what it means at all. It is the root filesystem of the *currently running OS* and can be arbitrarily chosen at boot time.

As you've booted the computer from the Arch Linux Install CD, right now you're looking at the contents of that CD (or more precisely, contents of a Squashfs archive `arch/x86_64/airootfs.sfs` found on the CD). **They have nothing to do with the contents of your *sda* disk.**

(You can see the complete layout using `findmnt`, although expect it to be slightly complex when "live CDs" are involved – usually they create a virtual `/` out of multiple layers via overlayfs.)

Later in the tutorial you will install a bootloader (GRUB2) to the disk, and *that* will have a configuration telling it to use something like `/dev/sda2` as the root partition, thereby mapping its contents to the installed system's `/`.